# how to group by nested properties using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, grouping, lodash

I have array of objects

```
{
    "work": [{
            "_id": "5c80c5c00c253823fc443337",
            "start": "2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z",
            "end": "2019-01-02T18:30:00.000Z",
            "employee": {
                "_id": "5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a",
                "status": "active",
                "location": "Chennai",
                "contact_number": "1234567890"
            },
            "allocation": 30
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c80c5ef0c253823fc443339",
            "start": "2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
            "end": "2019-09-30T18:30:00.000Z",
            "employee": {
                "_id": "5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a",
                "status": "active",
                "location": "Chennai",
                "contact_number": "1234567890"
            },
            "allocation": 100
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c80c60b0c253823fc44333a",
            "start": "2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-10-07T18:30:00.000Z",
            "employee": {
                "_id": "5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a",
                "status": "active",
                "location": "Chennai",
                "contact_number": "1234567890"
            },
            "allocation": 25
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c80c65e0c253823fc44333b",
            "start": "2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z",
            "end": "2019-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
            "employee": {
                "_id": "5c80c1940c253823fc44332b",
                "status": "active",
                "location": "Chennai",
                "contact_number": "1234567890"
            },
            "allocation": 50
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c80c7240c253823fc44333f",
            "start": "2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
            "end": "2019-10-09T18:30:00.000Z",
            "employee": {
                "_id": "5c80c26e0c253823fc44332e",
                "status": "active",
                "location": "Chennai",
                "contact_number": "1234567890"
            },
            "allocation": 25
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to convert them into

```
[{
    "_id": "5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a",
    "status": "active",
    "location": "Chennai",
    "contact_number": "1234567890",
    "work": [{
        "_id": "5c80c5c00c253823fc443337",
        "start": "2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-01-02T18:30:00.000Z",
        "allocation": 30
    }, {
        "_id": "5c80c5ef0c253823fc443339",
        "start": "2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-09-30T18:30:00.000Z",
        "allocation": 100
    }, {
        "_id": "5c80c60b0c253823fc44333a",
        "start": "2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "end": "2020-10-07T18:30:00.000Z",
        "allocation": 25
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "5c80c1940c253823fc44332b",
    "status": "active",
    "location": "Chennai",
    "contact_number": "1234567890",
    "work": [{
        "_id": "5c80c65e0c253823fc44333b",
        "start": "2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
        "allocation": 50
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "5c80c26e0c253823fc44332e",
    "status": "active",
    "location": "Chennai",
    "contact_number": "1234567890",
    "work": [{
        "_id": "5c80c7240c253823fc44333f",
        "start": "2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-10-09T18:30:00.000Z",
        "allocation": 25
    }]
}]
```

I have done it by partially using lodash and vanilla js and it works completely fine. but readability wise is completely bad. I want to achieve this using just lodash alone. Any help?

```
let ids: any = groupBy(this.project.work, function (res) {
    return res.employee._id;
});

for (let id in ids) {
    let tmp = [];
    let employee_added = false;
    ids[id].map((work) => {
        if (!employee_added) {
            tmp = work.employee;
            tmp['work'] = [];
            employee_added = true;
        }
        delete work.employee;
        tmp['work'].push(work);
    })

    this.employees.push(tmp);
}

console.log(this.employees);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it succinctly using plain JavaScript with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and desctructuring assignment:

```js
const data = {"work":[{"_id":"5c80c5c00c253823fc443337","start":"2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-01-02T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":30},{"_id":"5c80c5ef0c253823fc443339","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-09-30T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":100},{"_id":"5c80c60b0c253823fc44333a","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2020-10-07T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":25},{"_id":"5c80c65e0c253823fc44333b","start":"2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-10-04T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c1940c253823fc44332b","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":50},{"_id":"5c80c7240c253823fc44333f","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-10-09T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c26e0c253823fc44332e","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":25}]};

const result = Object.values(data.work.reduce((acc, work) => {
  const { employee: { _id, ...rest }, ...job } = work;
  const jobs = (acc[_id] || {}).work || [];
  acc[_id] = { _id, ...rest, work: [...jobs, job] };
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for it +1 Neat and Clean, But I am looking for lodash answers,  anyway I will accept your answer, If I could not find anything with lodash.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam didn't understand why you accepted the loadash version of answers (mine & Ori Drori's ans) and then unaccepted. this answer with plain JS looks good, and then you asked for lodash versoin (in the last comment of this ans), after that I came up with some lodash solution (thinking that may help you). Don'w know what exactly you were looking for.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee you really did a great job posting best answer. since I am using  typescript , there are some syntax issues with your answers and I was in hurry so I have used jo_va answer.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Hmm, actually it's not about my answer or anyone's answer, if you have any trouble, comment regarding any answer you should comment there, in order to have a bigger picture, for all SO users who might face this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully, this is what you are looking for.

1. First group it by `employee_.id`
2. Then map each group, take employee of first one (since every group
   must have one entry)
3. Then map all other members (and take outer part) of each group to `work`
   (everything apart from employee object)

Here is the example below:

```js
let works = [{"_id":"5c80c5c00c253823fc443337","start":"2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-01-02T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":30},{"_id":"5c80c5ef0c253823fc443339","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-09-30T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":100},{"_id":"5c80c60b0c253823fc44333a","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2020-10-07T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":25},{"_id":"5c80c65e0c253823fc44333b","start":"2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-10-04T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c1940c253823fc44332b","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":50},{"_id":"5c80c7240c253823fc44333f","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-10-09T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c26e0c253823fc44332e","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":25}]


let res = _(works)
            .groupBy('employee._id')
            .map(g => ({...g[0].employee, work: _.map(g, ({employee, ...rest}) => ({...rest}))}))
            .value();
            
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that uses lodash's `_.flow()` that groups by the employee id, and then creates an employee object with work array:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, head, get, omit } = _

const fn = flow(
  pr(groupBy, 'employee._id'),
  pr(map, group => ({ // create the employee objects
    ...get(head(group), 'employee'), // get the employee data and spread it
    work: group.map(o => omit(o, 'employee')) // create the work array by removing the employee from each work object
  }))
)

const data = {"work":[{"_id":"5c80c5c00c253823fc443337","start":"2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-01-02T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":30},{"_id":"5c80c5ef0c253823fc443339","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-09-30T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":100},{"_id":"5c80c60b0c253823fc44333a","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2020-10-07T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c16e0c253823fc44332a","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":25},{"_id":"5c80c65e0c253823fc44333b","start":"2019-01-01T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-10-04T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c1940c253823fc44332b","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":50},{"_id":"5c80c7240c253823fc44333f","start":"2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","end":"2019-10-09T18:30:00.000Z","employee":{"_id":"5c80c26e0c253823fc44332e","status":"active","location":"Chennai","contact_number":"1234567890"},"allocation":25}]}

const result = fn(data.work)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect +1 , Thanks for it

Comment: @OriDrori Try avoiding `omit`, rather take rest of the attributes as `{employee, ...rest}` and use `rest`